# CalendarView(DateTime, DateTime) - what property(s) of the appointments are used in the filter

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm using the CalendarView(DateTime, DateTime) constructor to filter appointment items by date. I'm unsure exactly what property(s) of an appointment is used to build this.

Does this filter solely on start date, or will it also return any appointment that ends inside the date range provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view tells the server to return appointments that occur between a time range and expand any recurring appointments within that range. As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa564515(v=exchg.150).aspx "All calendar items that have an end time that is before StartDate will not be returned" and "All calendar items that have a start time that is on or after EndDate will not be returned". Appointments that occur during the TimeWindow (even though they start before it) should be returned.

Cheers
Glen